# How to wait for a async function while running via shell in nodejs

Tags: node.js, command-line, async-await

I have a file

> demo.js

with a function that waits for fetch data from DB like this

```
exports.findNames = async () => {
  const names= await Student.find();
  console.log('Names:', names);
  return names;
};
```

So, while I testing this function via the shell/command line, which not waiting for the function to be completed. 
Tested like this 
`node ./demo findNames`

NB: Student is a model,
response sending from another file that's why not here. and it's not a middleware. Mongoose used as db tool

Comment: what is your demo js code?

Comment: its a simple nodejs file for getting students details from db using mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await` or `.then` the function in your `demo.js`. Let me give you an example:

**names.js**

```
exports.findNames = async () => {
    const names= await new Promise((res,rej)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            res([1,2,3])
        }, 100);
    });
    console.log('Names:', names);
};
```

**demo.js**

```
const name = require('./names');
(async ()=>{
    await name.findNames();
})();
```

**Output**

```
$ node demo.js
Names: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Comment: There is a problem with your demo.js code. Please post it here, because this example works.

Comment: Updated code with relevant info. res sending from another file that's why not here. and it's not a middleware.

Comment: You need to have a driver function like my `demo.js` to call your `findNames` function

Comment: It never returns.